# Will cutting the power (or closing the terminal) to a HDD-enclosure that's writing files, mainly 0's, damage HDD's filesystem or any part of the HDD?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Purpose: the safest way to abort `dd` copying in progress

(HDD, not SSD)

I have a 2TB HDD that is writing "files" from a 16GB media card reader. However, on the media card was only 1 100kb document file. The rest of the card is empty, as far as I recall.

The 2TB HDD has been copying the media card for over an hour and I would like to stop the process without damaging the HDD in any way.

I could use the terminal and just X out of the terminal and that should halt the process, or I could halt the power to the HDD enclosure.

I am leaning to just x'g out of the terminal. I have a feeling that this HDD is going to run for hours if I do not.

Which is the safest method?

UPDATE:

It's still running after 2 hours.

UPDATE:

The process finally finished.

Comment: How exactly is an HDD writing anything from the card on its own? HDDs are passive devices – they only respond to requests made by your OS. Some program running on your OS is reading files from the card and writing them to the HDD.

Comment: The hdd-enclosure is connected to the desktop/ OS. And so is the media card reader.

Comment: I have no idea what exactly you are doing. What is the exact command you want to abort?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski "sudo dd if=/dev/sdx bs=16M of=/dev/sdy". But it finally finished without me having to do abort it. I get the feeling that cutting the power to the 2 devices is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Aborting `dd` (Ctrl+C) will never physically damage HDDs or SSDs. It will most certainly “damage” whatever you’re cloning because the copy will be incomplete. // Cloning a storage medium to copy a single file is... slightly over the top? ;)

Comment: @DanielB Thanks. Yes, that would be ridiculous in most cases. In this case, it was just an experiment to see if my encryption was still present afterwards, given that I seemed to lose the encryption previously and wasn't sure why.

Answer (score 0):

To kill a process, just use

`ps -ef | grep <process name>`

and follow that up by

`kill <number you saw in previous output>`

This is much safer than killing it with SIGKILL.